# Can we form a rectangle with integral lengths using an odd number of copies of this domino?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, tiling, polyomino

Question:

> [image]
>
> This figure is made up of 6 unit cells. Can we form a rectangle with integral lengths using an odd number of copies of this domino? Rotating and flipping of the figure is allowed.

This question is a past year question from a school competition.

After trying for a while, one can hypothesize that the answer is no. However, I have no idea how one would go and prove this result. I tried all kinds of coloring like chessboard coloring and alternate row/column coloring. I also tried many numberings but to no avail.

Besides coloring and numbering, I do not see any other approach. Any help on this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Could $2(2n+1)$ be a perfect square?

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound ignorant, but may you explain how that is related? $2(2n+1)$ cannot be a perfect square, so we can never form a perfect square with an odd number of dominoes. However, I don't see how that is related to forming rectangles.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use $11$ copies of that hexomino to make a $6\times 11$ rectangle:

[image]

This seems to be the smallest solution. A $5\times 18$ rectangle can be seen in [Jean Marie's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4863523/362967), and here is a $9\times 10$ solution:

[image]

I found these solutions using my [Polyform Puzzle Solver](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/polysolver.htm) software.

Comment: Hi. Is there some way to rigorously prove this is the solution with least polyminoes?

Comment: @Sahaj Not that I know of, except just using a computer to exhaustively search all relevant smaller rectangles.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution in a $5 \times 18$ rectangle involving 15 copies of your "polyomino"  :

[image]

I knew that such a solution exist according to the results gathered at the end of this [article](https://www.emis.de/journals/DMTCS/pdfpapers/dmAB0107.pdf) but it took me some time before I find it... In this article, the existence of a solution in a $6 \times 11$ rectangle (explicitly found by Japp Sherphuis) is mentionned and, as well, the existence of a solution in a $9 \times 10$ rectangle which remains to be found...

Comment: The $9\times 10$ looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i073L.png).

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis Cudos ! I had been looking for it but was abandoning... How have you found it : by trial/error or by using a computer program ?

Comment: I used my own [Polyform Puzzle Solver](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/polysolver.htm) software.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis Thank you for your answer. I will have a look at your software ; but I must upload Java first...

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis You should include this solution into your answer.